# Is there a more efficient way to define similar public properties

Tags: c#

I've got a class with almost 20 public properties. These properties have in common that they are all strings and they are filled with data from different tables of a database.

Additionally the set is pretty normal while the get is special as I need to call a specific method. This is done for each property at the moment (see below).

My question here is: Is there another more efficient way of doing this, thus a way where I don't have to define each public property by hand in this way?

```
class myclass
{
     private string _Firstname;
     private string _Lastname;
     .....
     public string Firstname
     {
         get {
             return ModifyStringMethod(this._Firstname);
         }

         set {
             this._Firstname = value;
         }
     }
}
```

Like mentioned above every public property looks the same. The get calls ModifyStringMethod with the private member given as parameter while the set just sets the private member.

Comment: Does it have to be the getter, or could you do something with reflection? Perhaps a method `GetPropertyValue(string propertyName)`

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean. But in this exact example I need to return the modified string (the string modification method in my case just cuts of the string and adds "..." at the end if a string is too long to be displayed). Thus the get needs to return the modified value if you mean that

Comment: I have posted an example

Comment: Side note, but I would urge caution with non-readonly properties that do things like this in the getter.  This can create counter-intuitive behavior from lines like "x.Firstname = x.Firstname", which most people would not expect to change the value of Firstname.  You might consider creating a different readonly property for the 'transformed' view, like "DisplayFirstname".

Comment: I very much agree with Dan. If this is being done for display, I'd probably go so far as to create a separate facade class on top of this, so `MyClass` has read/write properties while `MyClassFacade` has readonly properties that expose `MyClass` properties modified for display.

Comment: I had just that thought when I saw I need that specific behaviour but also the normal one. Thus in the really used version I put in a property (flag) which defines if the Modifystring does modify the string or not. That way the one using that class can define on the fly which behaviour he want while still using the same methods and does not need to use different methods

Comment: Are you data binding?   If so it may be best to call a convert from the markup.

Answer (score 18):

You could try automatic code generation using [T4 template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). They are perfect when you have simple, repeating pattern of code and you are not expecting some cases to be slightly different from others.

Simply define a XML with list of property names and have T4 template generate partial class with each property.

Comment: s/hate/have/, I hope ;)

Comment: I was going to post T4 but you got there first. T4 is definitely better than, say, snippets because you need to add a change, you just modify and regenerate the T4, and **all** your properties have the same logic.

Comment: I agree with T4. Could you post an example implementation for completeness' sake?

Answer (score 12):

Another option is similar to Dion V.'s solution, but it utilizes implicit conversion to make the property behave like normal string from the outside and makes it possible to use simple automatic property. But this only works if `ModifyStringMethod` is static and doesn't require parameters from outside of the class.

```
public struct EllipsisString
{
    private string _value;

    public string Value {get { return _value; }}

    public EllipsisString(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    // implicit conversion from string so it is possible to just assign string to the property
    public static implicit operator EllipsisString(string value)
    {
        return new EllipsisString(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(EllipsisString original)
    {
        return SpecialMethod(original.Value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return SpecialMethod(Value);
    }

    private static string SpecialMethod(string value)
    {
        return value + "...";
    }
}
```

And usage is simple:

```
    private EllipsisString FirstName { get; set; }

    public void Method()
    {
        FirstName = "Thomas";
        Console.WriteLine(FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine(FirstName.Value);
    }
```

Comment: +1 if your property has special behaviour and characteristics that a simple string doesn't provide then it shouldn't be a simple string. Add that behaviour to the underlying type (in Euphorics example an EllipsisString) and add the implicit conversions to make them easier to deal with outside of your class if needed. Loosely related to mark seemans post on domain modelling http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/19/from-primitive-obsession-to-domain-modelling

Answer (score 6):

[PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/model/inotifypropertychanged) is another alternative.

You just apply an attribute over the class and write your properties with "get; set;" syntax.

PostSharp is a .NET tool that enables developers to apply aspects of code to be executed to there assembies, namespaces, classes, or methods.

Specifically, PostSharp enables developers to write less code by applying attributes to blocks of code that will later have the code reflecting that aspect get weived-in and executed with the code block selected. This approach significantly reduces "plumbing" that is redundant across a code base.

Common use cases include the following:

- Logging
- Security
- Undo/Redo
- INotifyPropertyChanged
- ExceptionHandling

Comment: Though I like the answer it is basically link-based. If the link breaks, the usefulness of your answer is hurt. I suggest adding a code snippet to demonstrate your solution and perhaps a little abstract about PostSharp for those not familiar with it. Thanks!

Comment: Even without the link breaking argument, a code sample will improve this answer. Once I get PostSharp, this answer still doesn't tell me what to do (even if PostSharp has a clear tutorial, this answer isn't self-contained).

Answer (score 4):

When I've been faced with this in the past, I've used Custom code snippets in VS to easily create the properties.  See the link [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx).

Then, when you have have to add a new property, you just invoke the code snippet and fill in the names of the items as necessary.

Although this doesn't necessarily negate the need to have many similar properties, 
it does make creation of them easier (along the same lines as using the T4 templates as mentioned above).

Answer (score 4):

If you can make your properties virtual, you can use an interceptor with Castle Dynamic Proxy.

An interceptor contains behavior that can execute when you call a given method.  In this case we ModifyStringMethod to the return value of a string property.

**How:**

1) Add reference to nuget package Castle.Core

2) Define your interceptor

```
public class ModifyStringMethodInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        invocation.Proceed();
        if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("get_") && 
            invocation.Method.ReturnType == typeof(string))
        {
            invocation.ReturnValue = 
              ModifyStringMethod((string)invocation.ReturnValue);
        }
    }

    private static string ModifyStringMethod(string input)
    {
        return (input ?? "") + "MODIFIED";
    }
}
```

The example above has an Intercept method that will be called when your property is called.  You can see in the example **invocation.Proceed()** this continues the call to the property.

Then it checks to see if its a get_ property and returns a string

```
 if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("get_") &&
     invocation.Method.ReturnType == typeof(string))
```

Then modifies the return value of the method.

```
 invocation.ReturnValue = ModifyStringMethod((string)invocation.ReturnValue);
```

3) Define your objects you want to add this behavior to with a virtual method **(notice I can also use auto implemented properties here) BONUS**

```
public class Intercepted
{
    public virtual string A { get; set; }
}
```

4) Then create instances of object using the ProxyGenerator class in DynamicProxy,

e.g

```
 public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pg = new ProxyGenerator();

        //  Intercepted will be an instance of Intercepted class with the           
        //  ModifyStringMethodInterceptor applied to it 
        var intercepted = pg.CreateClassProxy<Intercepted>(new ModifyStringMethodInterceptor());

        intercepted.A = "Set ... ";
        Console.WriteLine(intercepted.A);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Output is

```
Set ... MODIFIED
```

The benefit here is your objects are "clean" e.g they don't need to know about the ModifyStringMethodInterceptor and can contain auto implemented properties, which if you have plenty of these objects will reduce the amount of code by large amount.

Going one step further if you needed further control you could apply this behavior by adding an attribute to the class, e.g

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ModifyStringMethodAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Then the objects are defined as:

```
 public class Intercepted
 {
     public virtual string A { [ModifyStringMethod] get; set; }
 }
```

And a change to the interceptor:

```
if (invocation.Method.ReturnType == typeof(string) && 
    invocation.Method.GetCustomAttributes(true)
    .OfType<ModifyStringMethodAttribute>().Any())
        {
            invocation.ReturnValue = 
                  ModifyStringMethod((string)invocation.ReturnValue);
        }
```

To check for the attribute, and to then apply the method call.

Answer (score 3):

However, I'm personally not a fan of this solution, you could do something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private IDictionary<string, string> propertyValueByName = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return propertyValueByName[propertyName]; }
        set { propertyValueByName[propertyName] = ModifyStringMethod(value); }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return this["FirstName"]; }
        set { this["FirstName"] = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return this["LastName"]; }
        set { this["LastName"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An example using reflection

```
class MyClass
{
    public string FirstName { private get; set; }

    public string LastName { private get; set; }


    public string GetModifiedValue(string propertyName)
    {
        var prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        return ModifyStringMethod((string)prop.GetValue(this, null));
    }
}
```

So to get each modified value instead of using `MyClass.FirstName`, you would use `MyClass.GetModifiedValue("FirstName")`

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom code snippet here is an example of snipped that i have created for myself to automate creation of properties with change notification, you can use that as template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>propnot</Title>
            <Shortcut>propnot</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for property and backing field with property change event</Description>
            <Author>Radin Gospodinov</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>int</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>property</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>MyProperty</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>field</ID>
                    <ToolTip>The variable backing this property</ToolTip>
                    <Default>myVar</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp">
      <![CDATA[private $type$ $field$;

    public $type$ $property$
    {
        get { return this.$field$;}
        set {
    if(this.$field$ != value)   {
        $field$ = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.$property$);
      }
      }
    }
    $end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really have want to go with this approach, then code generation using something like T4 templates, or CodeSmith is probably the way to go, however I agree with @DanBryant that building your properties like this can lead to a counter intuitive class.  I would expect code like this to work:

```
X.FirstName = "Some random long name";
Assert.AreEqual("Some random long name", X.FirstName);
```

From your comment, with your class design this might not work (depending upon the truncation length in your `ModifyStringMethod` you may actually get `X.FireName == "Some rand..."`.  This seems wrong.

A better approach may be to implement the modification outside of the property behaviour possibly in an extension method.  So something like this:

```
public static class FormatStringExtensions {
    public static string ModifyStringForOutput(this string me) {
        if (me.Length > 10) {
            return me.Substring(0, 10) + "...";
        }
        return me;
    }
};
```

Would allow you to define your data classes using automatic properties:

```
public class myclass {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName {get; set; }
};
```

And then modify the string value from the properties as and when it's appropriate using the extension method:

```
    var instance = new myclass();

    instance.FirstName = "01234567890123";

    Console.WriteLine("Original Name {0}\nModified Name {1}\n", 
                      instance.FirstName,
                      instance.FirstName.ModifyStringForOutput());
```

This allows your properties to keep working as normal properties are expected, whilst giving your an easy way to access the formatted strings if required.

Answer (score 2):

An Alternative is to create a simple snippet using type and property name as variable. It's much faster to generate the class and you keep full control on your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your custom class to inherit from [DynamicObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public class MyExpando : DynamicObject
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    //Want to create properties on initialization? Do it in the constructor
    public MyExpando()
    {
        dictionary.Add("PreferredName", "Darth Sidious");
        dictionary.Add("GreatDialog", "Something, something, darkside!");
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        bool success = dictionary.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
        if (success)
            result = ModifiedValue(result); 
        return success;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        dictionary[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }
    private string ModifiedValue(object val)
    {
        //Modify your string here.

        if (val.ToString() != "Darth Sidious")
            return "Something something complete";
        return val.ToString();
    }
}
```

Want to create a property not in the constructor? Then you can just do

```
dynamic x = new MyExpando();
x.FirstName = "Sheev";
x.LastName = "Palpatine"
Console.WriteLine(x.PreferredName + " says : \"" + x.GreatDialog + "\"");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Great thing about this is that you can implement INotifyPropertyChanged and then call it in your `TrySetMember` method, you can also restrict access to your "Properties" setter or getter by just throwing an exception based off the property name in the TryGetMember or TrySetMember and just change the access modifier of dictionary for classes that inherit from `MyExpando` in order to simulate property inheritance.

Example of how to restrict access to to property setter.

```
    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
            return false;
        dictionary[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }
```